# Minimum stabbing problem for a set of convex polygons

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry, polygons

Let $S = \{P_1, P_2, ..., P_m\}$ be a set of convex polygons in $\mathbb R^2$ with a total of $n$ vertices. Polygons are defined by ordered lists of vertices, and each vertex is represented by a pair $(x,y)$ of its Cartesian coordinates. Polygons may have non-empty pairwise intersections.

A convex polygon is called *stabbed* by a line, if there is a non-empty intersection between them. A set $L$ of lines is called *stabbing set* for the set $S$, if each polygon in the $S$ is stabbed by at least one line from the $L$. Find a minimum stabbing set for the set $S$.

Are there any algorithms (papers, research) for this problem?

This problem is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75793014/minimum-number-of-lines-to-make-set-of-lines-connected) on SO.

Comment: Well, the problem is NP-hard, as it is a generalization of the NP-complete problem of covering/stabbing points by lines (see [my answer here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/159420/65339)). I don't whether there is any work on approximation algorithms or heuristics, though.

Comment: @Discretelizard - thank you! A possible heuristics - find *maximum* number of polygons, stabbed by one line, remove them from the set, and so on. Does it make sense?

Comment: That sounds reasonable. This problem can be seen as a variant of the set cover problem, so this heuristic is basically the standard [greedy algorithm for set-cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem?useskin=vector#Greedy_algorithm). Of course, an important difference between this problem and set cover is that the sets are not given explicitly here. In particular, you'll need to find a line stabbing a maximum number of polygons.

Comment: Wonder if this problem is complete for $\exists R$.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the problem is NP-hard. The best we can expect in this case is an approximation algorithm. Set-Cover is a natural choice for this. But the main hurdle here is that the subsets are not explicitly handed out to us. If we somehow have a subset of all possible stabbings, we immediately have a $O(\log n)$ approximation algorithm via Set-Cover. Just iteratively pick the set covering the largest number of elements that are yet to be covered.

Observe that if there is a line $l$ that stabs a subset of $S$, we can shift/rotate the line so that it still stabs the same set. In the extermal case, we would have a line $l'$ that passes through two vertices of any of the two polygons it stabs. Therefore, we are to only observe $n\choose 2$ such lines, which would give us the required subsets for Set-Cover.